# Android "Share to" → "Rename file"

Tags: gratis, android, file-management

Sometimes I want to immediately rename a picture or video I just took, to remember what it was. I don't want to open a file manager, it takes too long, so here is how it should work:

1. I have the file on the screen (any app that has a Share button)
2. I press "Share"
3. I press "Rename file"
4. A popup appear, I edit the filename, press OK.
5. The file is renamed and the popup disappears

[image: Send to rename intent]

Requirements:

- Fast to use
- Must work offline
- Free (ads OK), ideally open source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Gallery Rename Plugin**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tatuas.android.grp&hl=en) to rename an image directly from share menu. After installation, this option is added to the menu:

[image]

By clicking it, a renaming dialog is shown: (with some extra options)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (albeit with extra clicks) is by using [QuickPic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder&hl=en).

When you take a picture/video (or download one) and open QuickPic instantly after, it shows a pop-up like this:

[image]

Tapping it takes you straight to the recently captured picture.

There, in the overflow of the image, you can find the "rename" option:

[image]